# Column exchange still leaves the matrix unchanged

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

Professor Gilbert Strang writes in his notes ( does elimination on matrix $ U$ to reduce matrix into rref, denoted by matrix $R$ )

> $$
>  ... U=\left[\begin{array}{llll}
> 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\
> 0 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
> \end{array}\right] \rightarrow\left[\begin{array}{lllr}
> 1 & 2 & 0 & -2 \\
> 0 & 0 & 2 & 4 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
> \end{array}\right] \rightarrow\left[\begin{array}{lllr}
> 1 & 2 & 0 & -2 \\
> 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
> \end{array}\right]=R
> $$
> **By exchanging some columns**, $R$ can be rewritten with a copy of the identity matrix in the upper left corner, possibly followed by some free columns on the right. If some rows of $A$ are linearly dependent, the lower rows of the matrix $R$ will be filled with zeros:
> $$
> R=\left[\begin{array}{ll}
> I & F \\
> 0 & 0
> \end{array}\right]
> $$

How did the professor swap columns and still call the result $R$ ?

Comment: I don't think he means the specific matrix $R$ from the example, but rather a general matrix in reduced row-echelon from.  I agree that it's confusing to call two different things by the same name.

Comment: Hello saulspatz :), if I do the swap, I need to swap the variables as well and won't then it be fine?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  It would be less confusing if Strang had called the first matrix $R_1$ and the second $R_2$, or something like that.